# How to upload image to server in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-image-picker

I'm trying to upload image by using React Native axios. But I get this response. I tried every solutions but it didn't work. I'm using react-native-image-picker to get image

```
{ result: null,
  message: 'Wrong access',
  error: true,
  type: 'command_not_found' }
```

Here is my code

```
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', { uri: response.uri, name: response.fileName, type:response.type });
        let config = {
           headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
           }
        }
        axios({
           url: "URL",
           method: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           config
         })
         .then(result => console.log(result))
         .catch(error => console.log(error))

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with raw `fetch` api.

```
const createFormData = (photo) => {
  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("photo", {
    name: photo.fileName,
    type: photo.type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android" ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace("file://", "")
  });

  return data;
};
```

and then try to upload it again

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: createFormData(photo)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried you method but response is: { type: 'default', status: 200, ok: true }. It still doesn't upload image